# Azure Devops pipeline yaml create variable conditionally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to accomplish as follows in a `variable.yml` file (separate form pipeline file)

```yaml
- name: environment
    value: $[ stageDependencies.StartStage.StartJob.outputs['StartJobVariables.environment'] ]
- name: serviceConnectionName
    ${{ if eq( variables.environment, 'dev' ) }}: 
      value: $[ stageDependencies.StartStage.StartJob.outputs['StartJobVariables.devServiceConnectionName'] ] 
    ${{ if eq( variables.environment, 'qa' ) }}: 
      value: $[ stageDependencies.StartStage.StartJob.outputs['StartJobVariables.qaServiceConnectionName'] ] 
    ${{ if eq( variables.environment, 'prod' ) }}: 
      value: $[ stageDependencies.StartStage.StartJob.outputs['StartJobVariables.prodServiceConnectionName'] ]
```

so practically I would like to create a variable conditionally based on the value of another variable. How would I do this properly?

Comment: service-connections cannot be evaluated at runtime. They must be known in advance so that authorization and approvals can be processed.

Comment: I do not see service connection being asked; however, this statement is not 100% accurate. Service Connections can be dynamically read in from a separate variable file based on a parameter. This is a documented work around to the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a  sample yaml to achieve **create a variable conditionally based on the value of another variable.**
Select the **env parameters** (the purpose of its existence is to make testing simple, not hardly necessary.) and run

```
parameters:
  - name: env
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - qa
      - prod

stages:
  - stage: StartStage
    jobs:
      - job: StartJob
        steps:
          - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=environment;isOutput=true]'${{ parameters.env }}'"
            name: SetVar1
          ##
          - script: echo $(SetVar1.environment)
        ##
          - powershell: |
              if ($(SetVar1.environment) -eq 'dev'){
                echo echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceConnectionName;isOutput=true]devServiceConnectionName"
              }
              if ($(SetVar1.environment) -eq 'qa'){
                echo echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceConnectionName;isOutput=true]qaServiceConnectionName"
              }
              if ($(SetVar1.environment) -eq 'prod'){
                echo echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceConnectionName;isOutput=true]prodServiceConnectionName"
              }
            name: StartJobVariables
          # - ${{ if eq( $(SetVar1.environment), 'dev' ) }}:
          #   - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceConnectionName;isOutput=true]devServiceConnectionName"
          #     name: StartJobVariables
          # - ${{ if eq( $(SetVar1.environment), 'qa' ) }}:
          #   - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceConnectionName;isOutput=true]qaServiceConnectionName"
          #     name: StartJobVariables
          # - ${{ if eq( $(SetVar1.environment), 'prod' ) }}:
          #   - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceConnectionName;isOutput=true]prodServiceConnectionName"
          #     name: StartJobVariables


  - stage: EndStage
    dependsOn:
      - StartStage
    jobs:
      - job: EndJob
        variables:
          - name: serviceConnectionName
            value: $[ stageDependencies.StartStage.StartJob.outputs['StartJobVariables.serviceConnectionName'] ]
        steps:
          - script: echo $(serviceConnectionName)
```

---

and do not use:

```
- ${{ if eq( $(SetVar1.environment), 'dev' ) }}:
```

because the **Condition** expression is evaluated at compile time but **$(SetVar1.environment)** is evaluated at runtime. so when yaml engine rendering the whole yaml, the **$(SetVar1.environment)** value will be null, and throw out an error.

Comment: Hi, there is a small typo. The `prof` in parameters value should be `prod`.

Comment: Hi @Tian, thanks, already been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Service Connections are one of the few properties that cannot be set with a variable that is computed at runtime. The [pipeline-run-sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline) expands all templates out at compile-time in order to evaluate permissions and approvals. The only exception to this is if the variable is defined in the pipeline.yml at compile time.

However, if you wanted to conditionally construct a variable there are a few options:

#### Coalesce

Based on the presence of other variables, the `coalesce` function will evaluate one or more values and take the first non-null value:

```
variables:
- name: environmentName
  value: $[ coalesce( variables['one'], variables['two'], variables['three']) ]

- name: one
  value: $[ stageDependencies.myStage.myJob.outputs['myTask.myVarOne'] ]

- name: two
  value: $[ stageDependencies.myStage.myJob.outputs['myTask.myVarTwo'] ]

- name: three
  value: $[ stageDependencies.myStage.myJob.outputs['myTask.myVarThree'] ]
```

#### Dynamic variable name

The variables collection is a dictionary which you can access by name. If your variables follow a convention, simply construct the name of the variable using the `format` function:

```yaml
variables:
# assuming the possible output variables are either:
#  - devServiceConnection
#  - stgServiceConnection
#  - prdServiceConnection
- name: myVariable
  value: $[ stageDependencies.MyStage.MyJob.outputs[format('MyTask.{0}ServiceConnection', variables['environment'))] ]
```

#### Nested Replace

There is no `if( true, true-value, false-value)` function, but you can emulate it by nesting `replace` statements. If you need to do more than two conditions, it can get really confusing to look at, but it works.

```yaml
variable:
  # assume variables['envName'] can be dev, stg, or prd
  development: 'one'
  staging: 'two'
  production: 'three'
  
  # replace syntax ( original-value, search-string, replace-value)
  myName: $[ 
     replace(
       replace(
         replace( variables['envName'], 'dev', variables['development'])),
         'stg', variables['staging'])
       , 'prd', variables['myStg'])
    ]
```